# Steps for using swupdate in Yocto Project

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, intel, yocto

Can you please explain what all are steps are required to get started with swupdate in Yocto

I have Intel based board and I want to use swupdate for this project..

I have cloned poky, meta-intel branches, and generated core-image-minimal image, which is working

Now I cloned meta-swupdate layer and added it to bblayers.conf file. I am still not sure which is the bootloader being used for the Machine: intel-corei7-64. I have not seen neither grub or uboot.

Please help me in listing the steps for getting started.. I just know that I have to execute `bitbake swupdate-image`. What's next after that, which Image I have to flash..Where is the initrd image and how to copy it in the hddimg.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Did you look at the example layer [meta-swupdate-boards](https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate-boards)?

Comment: The problem is I am using Intel board..The examples I believe are based on ARM Boards with u-boot\

Comment: I was able to generate an .ext4 rootfs using bitbake swupdate-image, but have no idea on how to create a new partition and place this initrd into it.. Do you have any idea where all I need to make modifications

Comment: Which approach do you want? dual copy or single+recovery?

Comment: Single + recovery

Comment: It may be EFI boot guard, see that [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swupdate/OGT0tYz14xc) or ask swupdate mailing-list swupdate@googlegroups.com

Comment: What is the benefit of EFI Boot guard over GRUB?

Comment: From the github, I believe it may  be used for dual-copy technique